# Неправильная микроразметка при валидации (описание, картинка, ссылка)

Tags: битрикс, микроразметка

У меня проблема следующего характера:
Я на сайте Битрикс сделал микроразметку для каждого товара детально. Проверил эту микроразметку на сайте-валидаторе https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ .  Там задана картинка image и description . Но на валидаторе в режиме просмотра (там где можно посмотреть как будет выглядеть в google.ru) ссылка ведёт неизвестно куда, но не на ту страницу которую надо. description не высвечивается, картинка не выходит. Как всё это исправить? Вот файл с микроразметкой:

```html
<div class="prod-block main" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
 <div itemprop="name" style="display:none;"><h1><?=$arResult['NAME'];?></h1></div>
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemprop="aggregateRating">
   <div itemprop="ratingValue" style="display:none;">5</div>
   <div itemprop="ratingCount" style="display:none;">5</div>

 </div>

 <meta itemprop="description" content="<?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'];?>">


    <div class="gallery-switch">
        <ul class="clr">
            <li class="active" data-view="0"><span>Левозаходная лестница</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-wr clr">
        <div class="gallery-wr fl">
            <div class="gallery active clr left" data-view="0">
                <div class="pager-wr">
                    <div class="pager clr">
                        <?foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['IMAGES']['VALUE'] as $index => $imageId):?>
                            <a class="pager-item active" data-slide-index="<?=$index?>">
        <meta itemprop="image" content="<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>">
                                <div itemprop="image" class="image" style="background-image:url(<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>);"></div>
                            </a>
                        <?endforeach;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main-photo-wr">
                    <ul class="main-slider">
                        <?foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['IMAGES']['VALUE'] as $imageId):?>
                            <li>
        <!--<meta itemprop="image" content="<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>">-->
                                <div itemprop="image" class="image" style="background-image:url(<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>"></div>
                            </li>
                        <?endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer fr"  itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
            <div class="price-box">
                <div class="price-text">Стоимость от</div>
    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"];?>">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
                <div class="price">
                    <?=number_format($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"], 0, ',', ' ')?> <span class="unit">руб.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btns">
                <a class="warranty">Гарантия 3 года</a>
                <a class="location" href="/articles/purchase/"><span>Где купить?</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


  
 $requestFormPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/include_areas/request_form.php';
 if(file_exists($requestFormPath))
 {
  include_once($requestFormPath);
 }

?>



    <div class="params-wr">
        <div class="h3">Характеристики</div>
        <ul class="params-list clr">
            <?foreach ($arResult["PROPERTIES"] as $pid => $arProperty):
                if ($pid == 'IMAGES' ||
                    $pid == 'PRICE' ||
                    $pid == 'MODEL' ||
                    $pid == 'HEIGHT_ANONS' ||
                    $pid == 'SHOW_ON_MAINPAGE' || 
                    $arProperty['VALUE'] == '') continue;?>
                <li>
                    <div class="param clr">
                        <div class="label fl">
                            <?=$arProperty['NAME']?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="value fr">
                            <?=$arProperty['VALUE']?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<?if ($arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']):?>
    <div class="prod-block info">
        <div class="h3">Подробное описание</div>
        <div class="text">
            <?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?endif;?>

<div class="prod-block last clr">
    <div class="column reviews">
        <div class="h3">Отзывы</div>
        <div class="reviews-wr" id="reviewsDetailAjaxContainer">  <div class="review">
                <div class="header clr">
                    <div class="author fl">Марина</div>
                    <ul class="rating fr clr">
                        <li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li>    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="content">Лестницы «Темп» увидели впервые в Леруа Мерлен. Присмотрели, отметили, запомнили. Изучать ассортимент стали дома, потом поехали уже в торгово-выставочный зал на Волоколамском. Очень удобно все представлено. Понравилось качество и разнообразие представленных пород.
                    Помогли определиться с размерами. Брали с собой план дома для простоты объяснения. Мы изначально были нацелены на правостороннюю, но нам объяснили, чем нам это будет мешать. По факту купили с левым заходом, очень довольны, действительно удобно. Понимаем, что без консультации могли сделать похуже. Спасибо большое за участие в выборе!</div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <div class="date">13.02.2016</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="review">
                <div class="header clr">
                    <div class="author fl">Василий Олегович</div>
                    <ul class="rating fr clr">
                        <li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class="set"></li><li class=""></li>    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="content">Переделывали старый дачный дом. Он небольшой и проход на второй этаж очень узкий. Особенности конструкции такие, что расширить проем или нельзя, или проще перестроить дом, чем это делать. Искали лестницу готовую, которая могла бы вписаться. Долго сами мудрили, хотели делать самостоятельно. Сходили к соседям, у них похожий проект дома. Они заказывали лестницу на заказ в Темпе.
                    В итоге нам сделали винтовую с учетом особенностей. Хорошо получилось. Пространство вокруг осталось, а то пройти нельзя было. Заход удобный. Надежная. Не дешево, но у нас особо было без вариантов: или так, или перестраивать.</div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <div class="date">07.04.2016</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<a class="show-more"><span>Показать ещё</span></a>-->
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: все у вас работает с картинкой.
Просто вы в свойство `meta` в `content` пихаете `html`, когда она принимает только текст, и у вас дальше немного едет структура из-за этого. 
Во-вторых вы потеряли кусок пхп кода `$requestFormPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/include_areas/r` тут, он у вас просто на странице выводится.
А так, если задать адекватный дексриптион, работает - http://joxi.ru/VrwzpNntOgGxWA
А ссылка у вас относительная, поэтому если скопируете и вставите в гугл, конечно вы никуда не попадете, почитайте  http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: Oleksandr, насчёт потерянного пхп-кода - всё в порядке. Это я просто скопировал неправильно и вставил сюда. Я сделал следующее: написал <meta itemprop="description" content="<?='qwertyuiop'//=$arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT'];?>"> .... При предварительном просмотре как должен выглядеть description?

Comment: Вот пока как у меня: http://joxi.ru/E2p3QnBu9XGO4m

Comment: Точнее как задать неотносительную, а абсолютную ссылку именно в микроразметку? Я просто чайник в микроразметках.

Answer (score 2):

Я сделал как надо. Вот прикладываю код:

```
<div class="prod-block main" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
<div style="display:none;"><h1 itemprop="name"><?=$arResult['NAME'];?></h1></div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemprop="aggregateRating">
        <div itemprop="ratingValue" style="display:none;">5</div>
        <div itemprop="ratingCount" style="display:none;">5</div>
</div>

<div itemprop="description" style="display:none;">
    <?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'];?>
</div>



<link itemprop="url" href="<?='https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" />

<div class="gallery-switch">
    <ul class="clr">
        <li class="active" data-view="0"><span>Левозаходная лестница</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="top-wr clr">
    <div class="gallery-wr fl">
        <div class="gallery active clr left" data-view="0">
            <div class="pager-wr">
                <div class="pager clr">
                    <?foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['IMAGES']['VALUE'] as $index => $imageId):?>
                        <a class="pager-item active" data-slide-index="<?=$index?>">
                            <meta itemprop="image" content="<?='https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].CFile::GetPath($imageId);?>">
                            <div class="image" style="background-image:url(<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>);"></div>
                        </a>
                    <?endforeach;?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-photo-wr">
                <ul class="main-slider">
                    <?foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['IMAGES']['VALUE'] as $imageId):?>
                        <li>
                            <img itemprop="image" src="<?='https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].CFile::GetPath($imageId);?>" style="display:none;">
                            <div class="image" style="background-image:url(<?=CFile::GetPath($imageId)?>"></div>
                        </li>
                    <?endforeach;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="offer fr"  itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="price-box">
            <div class="price-text">Стоимость от</div>
            <meta itemprop="price" content="<?=$arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"];?>">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
            <div class="price">
                <?=number_format($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"], 0, ',', ' ')?> <span class="unit">руб.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
            <a class="warranty">Гарантия 3 года</a>
            <a class="location" href="/articles/purchase/"><span>Где купить?</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


    <? $requestFormPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/include_areas/request_form.php';if(file_exists($requestFormPath)){include_once($requestFormPath);}?>



<div class="params-wr">
    <div class="h3">Характеристики</div>
    <ul class="params-list clr">
        <?foreach ($arResult["PROPERTIES"] as $pid => $arProperty):
            if ($pid == 'IMAGES' ||
                $pid == 'PRICE' ||
                $pid == 'MODEL' ||
                $pid == 'HEIGHT_ANONS' ||
                $pid == 'SHOW_ON_MAINPAGE' || 
                $arProperty['VALUE'] == '') continue;?>
            <li>
                <div class="param clr">
                    <div class="label fl">
                        <?=$arProperty['NAME']?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="value fr">
                        <?=$arProperty['VALUE']?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</div>
```